# wildcard/regular expressions in List.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listjs

I have a news page in which I would like to have buttons that filter by month, using the span class 'date'. Using list.js, I can only filter by using an exact matching string. Is there a wildcard I can use to display all items that contain the word November

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn" id="filter-oct">October</button>
<button class="btn" id="filter-nov">November</button>
<div class="newsitem">
    <h2>News title</h2>
    <p><span class="date">Thursday 31 November 2013</span> Some text, more text</p>
    <p>Should you have any concerns, require additional information or wish to discuss this matter further please contact me</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'date' ]
  };
  var featureList = new List('election-list', options);
  $('#filter-nov').click(function() {
    featureList.filter(function(item) {
      if (item.values().date == "November 2013") {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

It's on this line where it does the matching - but only matches the exact word/s

**if (item.values().date == "November 2013") {**

I've tried using &= and ^= to try to get a match but neither work.

Thanks

Comment: Answered it myself. $('#filter-nov').click(function() { featureList.filter(function(item) { if (item.values().date.match(/..November../)) { return true; } else { return false; } }); return false; });

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer and mark the answer as 'accepted'. This way we can close this question.